# Winforms DateTimePicker dropdown does not show correct maxdate range on first opening

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have 2 dateTimePickers. If dtp1 value changes then the dtp2 maxdate should update (and restrict selection of dtp dropdown ).
However when dtp1 value is changed and I open dtp2 dropdown, it shows the old maxdate. Only when I close dtp2 dropdown and re-open it, does dialog change.

When opening dtp2 dropdown this valueChanged gets called (confirmed with debugger) and maxdate is set. So I would believe this is sufficient, (but did not work).

```
    private void dtp2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtp2.Maxdate= dtp1.Value;
    }
```

things I've tried.

```
dtp1.Select();
SendKeys.Send("%{DOWN}"); //simulating key presses is hacky and somthing I want to avoid if possible.

dtp1.Invalidate(); 
dtp1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Have you tried setting dtp2.Maxdate when dtp1 value changed? Now you assign it in dtp2 value changed handler

Comment: `ValueChanged` is not raised when you open the Calendar DropDown. Do what the previous comment suggests.

Comment: @treze I have thought about that, but I'm working in a framework that requires me to write more code that way, for the same result. I will try, but theoretically it should not work.

Comment: @Jimi I'm sorry but this just isn't true. As said before I used a debugger to confirm. here is the link where I show it in a gif. https://i.imgur.com/KTGV49X.gif

Comment: There is also the DropDown event itself..maybe this will work. But it's possible that you need to apply the Maxdate before the dropdown in order of it to be considered by the control. Therefore you need to assign it right after dtp1 changed.

Comment: Again. The ValueChanged event is not raised when you open up the DropDown. It's raised when you change the Value (somewhere/somehow) or you check/uncheck the CheckBox (somewhere/somehow). So, you're doing either of these somewhere else. -- I don't see what problem could you have with the suggested solution. - If you're not using standard Controls, state that clearly.

Comment: yes, I have tried it. It was this. I was googling for the "event stack" for dtp dropdown but could not find it. Then I was so sure the maxdate was set in debugging. Oh Well. thanks @treze @Jimi.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this post is, outside for me. I have no issue it got deleted.